# SSRS Group Properties

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I am creating report FetchXML report and using group on raw size.
my report look like 
[image]

but I want group like
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the Raw Size to the Row Group header row(probably your blank first row below your table headings), then delete the first two columns.  Then I would insert a row within the Row Group headers, below the Raw Size.  Then I would copy the current column headings onto that row.  Then I would delete the current column heading row. For those dynamic headings (eg. Tire Size / Kit Size, period columns) I would replace static text with expressions. Finally I would use the Add Totals command on the Total detail cell to create a sub-total row for the Raw Size Group, then add the other fields needed on that row.